# .html file without any HTML tags

Tags: html, tags

Beginner question:

Every .html page we create requires  tags to start and end html file an recognize it as a html file.

But even when I don't give any HTML tags and simply write a text in .html file, the file gets opened in the browser with the text I have written in the .html file without using any of the HTML tags.

How is the text getting displayed in the browser without using any HTML tags?

Does the browser automatically add HTML tags behind the scenes??

When I viewed the page source in that also it shows simply the text not the HTML tags...

This is a very simple question but driving me nuts please help me

Comment: a) the filename extensions does not matter too much depending on how you open the file. it might be served as plain text. b) you profit from multiple layers of error correction and graceful degradation.

Comment: It's actually possible to make a blank html file, then send a CSS file via http headers (http://meyerweb.com/eric/thoughts/2009/01/22/using-http-headers-to-serve-styles/), then use html:after and before and body:after and before to produce the website. Don't recommend it though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes the browser automatically add HTML tags behind the scenes:

look:

My HTML file:
[image: HTML File]

In my browser (<kbd>F12</kbd> in chrome to get this OR <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> to get the source code):
[image: Behind the scenes]

Comment: I use firefox.In Firefox when I normally view the source code HTML is not getting displayed but when I view the source code in developer console,it is getting displayed.. Thanks for the answer.. :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you don't supply any tags, the browser will add some default tags. It knows it's HTML because the server sends the header

```
Content-type: text/html
```

If you open the Developer Tools (usually with <kbd>F12</kbd>) you can view the synthesized DOM and see the tags that the browser added automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Browsers aren't just software which renders perfect (X)HTML.

They do quite different and often more complicated jobs like:

- Fixing malformed HTML
- Adding missing tags

If you want to know which HTML structure gets rendered by the browser, take a look at the developer console.

Additionally, the file extensions `.html` or `.htm` do not matter. The MIME type which gets sent by the server determines the render mode.
This is why you could create an URI route `http://example.com/test.gif` which renders as a normal HTML page.

Only if the server (e.g. when accessing from your hard drive) does not provide a MIME type, the browser may try its [Content sniffing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_sniffing) algorithms.

Answer (score 0):

Because of the .html extension the browser automatically knows that it is HTML, meaning you don't need the HTML tags (however, this is bad practice)...

As for the text being displayed, that is because the text does not need to be inside any special tags in order for it to be shown.

I hope this helps you a bit, let me know if you need further help!

Answer (score -1):

I do not know whether the question is still current, but one solution is to open the HTML document in MS Word. In this case you see only the formatted content.